# How to animate a floating UIView in ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I am trying to have a `UIView` animate as a floating object, or as a Balloon :D
The `UIView` is in the middle of the screen, and I want it to keep floating randomly around its first initiated spot. Not across the screen or anything like that, just floating in the area of 5 pixels around it.

Any suggestions? :D

I tried this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     myCircleUIView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation([self randomFloatingGenerator], [self randomFloatingGenerator]);
                 }
                 completion:NULL];
```

`randomFloatingGenerator` generates a number between -5 and 5. Problem is, it only executes once, and keeps repeating with the same random values.

**EDIT1:**
Now I have tried This

```
-(void)animationLoop{

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations: ^{ myCircleUIView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation([self randomFloatingGenerator], [self randomFloatingGenerator]); }
                     completion:
     ^(BOOL finished) {
         [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          animations:^{ myCircleUIView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,0);
                          }
                          completion:
          ^(BOOL finished) {[self animationLoop];}];
     }];
```

But it is still not working, the animation is.... Cracky... I think I am doing some stupid mistake that I need a second set of eyes to help me with.

**EDIT2:**
Fixed it.

```
 -(void)animationLoop{
    CGPoint oldPoint = CGPointMake(myCircleUIView.frame.origin.x, myCircleUIView.frame.origin.y);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations: ^{ myCircleUIView.frame = CGRectMake(myCircleUIView.frame.origin.x + [self randomFloatingGenerator], myCircleUIView.frame.origin.y + [self randomFloatingGenerator], myCircleUIView.frame.size.width, myCircleUIView.frame.size.height); }
                     completion:
     ^(BOOL finished) {
         [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          animations:^{ myCircleUIView.frame = CGRectMake(oldPoint.x, oldPoint.y, myCircleUIView.frame.size.width, myCircleUIView.frame.size.height);}
                          completion:
          ^(BOOL finished) {[self animationLoop];}];
     }];
}
```

Thanks for the help anyone.

**EDIT 3:**

Someone posted an enhanced code.

Comment: use NSTimer and call above code in it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Shamy's solution, improved, fixed and CPU safe.

```
-(void)animateFloatView:(UIView*)view{

    // Abort the recursive loop
    if (!view)
        return;

    CGPoint oldPoint = CGPointMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6
                     animations: ^{ view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y - 15, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height); }
                     completion:
     ^(BOOL finished) {

         if (finished) {
             [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6
                              animations:^{ view.frame = CGRectMake(oldPoint.x, oldPoint.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);}
                              completion:
              ^(BOOL finished2) {
                  if(finished2)
                      [self animateFloatView:view];
              }];

         }
     }];
}
```

Whenever you want to stop the animation (necessary when leaving the View Controller), call the function using *nil*, as this:

```
    [self recursiveFloatingAnimation:nil];
```

Not stoping the animation will cause the recursive loop to run infinitely and overwhelm the CPU stack.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0.1, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
    self.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x, y: self.frame.origin.y - 15, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height)
},completion: nil )
```

Comment: If you make the Delta in both X and Y with two random variables between -15 and 15 it will be perfect for what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

It will behave in that way. As you are repeating the animation not the function. So it will repeat same animation every time you set at first call. Do it like:

```
@interface AAViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView * floatingView;
@end

@implementation AAViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    _floatingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    [_floatingView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:_floatingView];

    [self circleUIViewFloating];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Circle UIView floating

- (void) circleUIViewFloating {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                     animations:^{
                         _floatingView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation([self randomFloatingGenerator : 270], [self randomFloatingGenerator:480]);
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [self circleUIViewFloating];
                     }];
}

- (int) randomFloatingGenerator : (int) max{
    return arc4random() % max;
}
```

Here is [complete running project](https://github.com/rptwsthi/DevelopmentSupportWorkspace/tree/master/ViewAnimationsTest) for this.

Comment: The problem with this is that it translates the object, so when it's done, its position isn't the one it started from, but the one it translated to. I don't want to translate the object, I just want to animate it. If I use the re-annimate it will keep jumping, if I don't use it it will keep floating on its own, not around its original coordinates as I am trying to do.

Comment: I'm not sure whether UIkit is the right choice for your task. Have a look at spriteKit, Cocos2d or similar if you want to code a game!

Comment: Otherwise look at the timing curve. Use easeInEaseOut to avoid abrupt movements.

Comment: It seems like the problem is that, it only starts animating from the position I want it to animate TO not from, don't get why though...

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the hovering or floating effect using `CABasicAnimation`.

You will have to include the `QuartzCore` framework to use this.

**Swift 4.2:**

```
import QuartzCore

let hover = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    hover.isAdditive = true
    hover.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint.zero)
    hover.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: -5.0))
    hover.autoreverses = true
    hover.duration = 0.8
    hover.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    myCustomView.layer.add(hover, forKey: "hoverAnimation")
```

Make sure to remove the animation when the view is no longer being shown.

```
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // Stop animating when view is going to disappear
        myCustomView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)animationLoop{
CGPoint oldPoint = CGPointMake(myCircleUIView.frame.origin.x, myCircleUIView.frame.origin.y);
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations: ^{ myCircleUIView.frame = CGRectMake(myCircleUIView.frame.origin.x + [self randomFloatingGenerator], myCircleUIView.frame.origin.y + [self randomFloatingGenerator], myCircleUIView.frame.size.width, myCircleUIView.frame.size.height); }
                 completion:
 ^(BOOL finished) {
     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      animations:^{ myCircleUIView.frame = CGRectMake(oldPoint.x, oldPoint.y, myCircleUIView.frame.size.width, myCircleUIView.frame.size.height);}
                      completion:
      ^(BOOL finished) {[self animationLoop];}];
 }];
}
```

Comment: This recursive solution blocks the main thread. I highly discourage the use of this solution unless you stop it before leaving the VC. Also, you would need to check if the current animation is ready before calling the again, else you'll get into an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes I was thinking this, so how would you stop and start the animations? Use UIViewPropertyAnimator?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 2.1** Version Here:

```
func animateFloatView(view: UIView?) {
    // Abort the recursive loop
    guard let view = view else { return }


    let oldPoint: CGPoint = CGPointMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, animations: {() -> Void in
        view.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y - 15, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)
        }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
            if finished {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, animations: {() -> Void in
                    view.frame = CGRectMake(oldPoint.x, oldPoint.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)
                    }, completion: {(finished2: Bool) -> Void in
                        if finished2 {
                            self.animateFloatView(view)
                        }
                })
            }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.1:**

```
func animateFloatView(_ view: UIView?) {
    guard let view = view else { return }
    let oldYCoordinate = view.center.y

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations: {
        view.center.y -= 15
    }, completion: { _ in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations: {
            view.center.y = oldYCoordinate
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.animateFloatView(view)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: How do you break this animation, like to stop it from floating?